# angular2 cannot find name require

Tags: angular, typescript, require

I want to use a new component named ng2-material-select in my application.
Added it into systemjs.config.js

```
var map = {
 'Ng2Select': '/node_modules/ng2-material-select',
 "angular2-jwt": "/node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt"
};

var packages = {
    'Ng2Select': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
```

But when I start the application, I face following error:

> Error loading http://192.168.0.46:3002/ng2-material-select as "ng2-material-select" from http://192.168.0.46:3002/app/module.js

also there is following error in node_modules/ng2-material-select/index.ts,which I think it may causes problem in loading:

> cannot find name require :

```
const components = require('./ng2-select.bundle.js');
```

I updated angularjs   and typescript ,but still problem does not solve.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you added Ng2SelectModule in your AppModule like this - `import { Ng2SelectModule } from '../src/ng2-select.module';`

Comment: Yes, in module.ts I have import { Ng2SelectModule } from 'ng2-material-select';

Answer (score 0):

I believe your systemjs.config.js mappings are wrong.

This ..

```
'Ng2Select': '/node_modules/ng2-material-select'
```

points to a TS file, I believe you need to point to a JS file. I believe you want ..

```
'Ng2Select': '/node_modules/ng2-material-select/dist/ng2-select.bundle.js'
```

poke around in the /node_modules/ng2-material-select folder and make sure you are pointing to the right file.

(I believe the JS file is the file that the TS file is trying to require).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following line in the typescript file:

```
declare function require(fileName: string): any;
```

Then, in the constructor, read a json-file:

```
this.myConfig = require('../assets/config.' + location.hostname + '.json');
```